# Algorithm/Function about computing taxi fare

Tags: algorithm, math, pseudo-class, computation

Let's say that a taxi charges $3.10 for the first fifth of a mile. Then for each additional fifth of a mile it charges half a dollar. For every minute of waiting or delay it charges half a dollar. However, this delay charge is applied instead of the mileage charge for each minute during which the speed of the taxi is slower than the brea-even point. The break-even point is the speed at which a fifth of a mile is driven in one minute. We are assuming the taxi goes at constant speed.
I am trying to write an algorithm or function that takes in the total distance and total time travelled by taxi and outputs the fare. However, I am having difficulty factoring in the delay charge.

So if the taxi is going at constant speed then ideally it would travel x miles during the time given (constant speed * time interval).
If we subtract the actual miles travelled from this value, we would get the number of "wasted" miles that could have been travelled but were not. 
And then I lose the train of thought and I am not sure where to go from there. Any help/hint would be appreciated.

Comment: at the end of each minute, calculate how many miles traveled. if it's less than fifth of a mile, charge half a dollar; otherwise charge for the miles traveled.

Comment: you are only given the TOTAL time and the TOTAL distance travelled not a minute by minute report.

Answer (score 3):

There is no single output to this problem when given only total_time and total_distance. I will 
show two instances resulting in same total_time and total_distance but different total fares.

```
Instance 1: 
1st min: travels 0.4 mile; fare = 3.1+0.5 = 3.6
2nd min: waits at signal; fare = 0.5 for waiting a min at speed less than break even point
3rd min: travels 0.8 mile; fare = 0.5*4 = 2
total_fare = 3.6 + 0.5 + 2 = 6.1

Instance 2: 
1st min: travels 0.4 mile; fare = 3.1+0.5 = 3.6
3rd min: travels 0.4 mile; fare = 0.5*2 = 1
3rd min: travels 0.4 mile; fare = 0.5*2 = 1
total_fare = 3.6 + 1 + 1 = 5.6
```

However, in both cases total_distance = 1.2 mile and total_time = 3 min but the fares came out to be different.

Comment: The problem description does say "We are assuming the taxi goes at constant speed." Your taxi is behaving like a real taxi, stopping due to traffic signals etc., so it is not going at a constant speed.

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan, the problem description also says, "For every minute of waiting or delay", which contradicts with "We are assuming the taxi goes at constant speed", how can the taxi wait or delay if it is going at a constant speed? You just proved my point. For the sake of argument if we assume "real" constant speed for the whole time, then constant_speed=total_distance/total_time and solution of muratgu is correct, although the question doesn't say anything about nominal time. The fare for second scenario of muratgu could be $33.1 instead of $13 if we don't consider nominal time.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, this should work.  If this isn't correct, please provide example inputs and outputs so I know when I have it right.  The example code is in JavaScript.

### [interactive example](http://jsfiddle.net/6ZBUg/)

Constants:

```
var baseRate = 3.10;
var mileRate = 0.50;
var minuteRate = 0.50;


function fare(miles, minutes) {
    var n = baseRate, mode;
```

Under a fifth of a mile, so base rate

```
    if (miles <= 1/5) {
        n = baseRate;
    }
```

Per mile charge is added to the base rate.  We subtract the 1/5 miles first.

```
    else if (miles < minutes / 5) {
        miles -= 1/5;
        n += mileRate * miles;
    }
```

We went less than a fifth of a mile per minute, so charge the per-minute rate.

```
    else {
        n += minutes * minuteRate;
    }
    return n;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are calculating the charge at the very end of the trip, then you just need to calculate the overall speed, and nominal time based on the break-even rule.

For one scenario, let's say the trip took 30 mins for 10 miles.

```
t = 30m
d = 10mi
s = 10/30 = 1/3 mi/m which is > (1/5 mi/m)
```

There are no delays so the the cost is based on miles.

```
cost = $3.10 + (10mi - 1/5mi) * $0.50 = $8.00
```

For another scenario, let's say the trip took 60 mins for 10 miles.

```
t = 60m
d = 10mi
s = 10/60 = 1/6 mi/m which is < (1/5 mi/m)
```

The nominal time for this trip is 50 minutes (10 / (1/5)), so there is a 10m delay, added to the charge.

```
cost = $3.10 + (10mi - 1/5mi) * $0.50 + (10m * $0.50) = $13
```